# Drupal 7: how to display the content of the field without the label in node--type.tpl.php?

Tags: theming, nodes

I created a content type called Community (machine name: community).

So I created file `node--community.tpl.php` to rearrange the fields.

I can do it like this...

```
<?php 
  print render($content['field_phone']);
?>
```

it prints (with Phone in bold)...

```
Phone: 
(888) 555-555
```

But I just want it to display the raw value with no label and no surrounding HTML. I just want  to print `(888) 555-555`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by editing the Content Type and managing the display of your fields - click the Manage Display tab.

Once in there, you can change the label to hidden.

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's the right solution.